# Heroku cannot find symbol after downloading dependency successfully

Tags: scala, heroku, dependencies

When trying to deploy my Play! 2.2.1 app to Heroku, I receive the following error with an external dependency:

```
[info] downloading http://blopker.github.com/maven-repo/ws/wamplay/wamplay_2.10/0.2.6-SNAPSHOT/wamplay_2.10-0.2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] ws.wamplay#wamplay_2.10;0.2.6-SNAPSHOT!wamplay_2.10.jar (67ms)
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 42 Scala sources and 7 Java sources to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/wamplay/controllers/routes.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
[error] public static final wamplay.controllers.ReverseWAMPlayServer WAMPlayServer = new wamplay.controllers.ReverseWAMPlayServer();
```

It seems that routing to a static method inside a dependency is not possible?

The dependency is in fact downloaded, but compiling fails. I'm using Java Version 1.7.